# Как в android организовать Https соединение?

Tags: android, android-sdk, http, веб-программирование, https

Как в android приложении сделать https соединение?Может есть какие-нибудь библиотеки упрощающие разработку,или в android-sdk есть что-нибудь?

Comment: Вас интересует отличие HTTPS от HTTP? Или вас интересует эта история с самого начала? Читайте про Retrofit, в интернете куча примеров. https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: Мне нужно понять с помощью каких инструментов можно организовать работу ssl протокола на android

Comment: https есть "из коробки" и у родного клиента, и у okhttp/retrofit. просто используйте url, начинающийся с https://